# Is there a formula to change the colour of a cell, based on todays date?

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet in Google Docs which has a new column for each day, the header being the date it was filled out.

I want to to set the background colour as grey for every column which has a header/date that comes before today.

(Note: the cells I want to set the background colour for do not contain a date. It's only the header of the column)

Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt of you can use Formulas in Conditional formatting in Google Spreadsheet else it would have been easy. Having said that, I believe that the only way to achieve this is via Google Apps Script.

Comment: A quick Google Search got me this. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16745/google-spreadsheets-conditional-formatting

Comment: In Excel, you would simply select all your columns, then create a new Conditional Formatting rule (select "Use a formula...") and enter `=A$1<TODAY()`. Siddharth's link will get you started on a GDocs solution -- just use columns instead of rows and change the conditional statement to check the date rather than positive/negative/empty values.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is applicable as i do not use Google Docs but it works in excel.

```
Left column                  right column

Tuesday, July 24, 2012       =IF(B1<B3,1,0)
Wednesday, July 25, 2012     =IF(B2<B3,1,0)
Thursday, July 26, 2012      =IF(B3<B3,1,0)
```

Result:

```
Left column                  right column

Tuesday, July 24, 2012       1
Wednesday, July 25, 2012     1
Thursday, July 26, 2012      0
```

Now apply conditional formatting based on the value of the right column.

It does not matter if cells contain the date. The date is only necessary for a condition evaluation. The code that will conditionally format the background can easily operate on range of cells.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand this. Why do I need the right column? Why not just format the cell based off the left column? It seems like this method would be using 2 formulas instead of 1.

"It does not matter if cells contain the date" - I only know how to format a cell if it contains the date itself. Its all that Googling the problem gives me too.

Do you know how to change the background of a cell based off information in another cell?

Answer (score 0):

The new Google Sheets can do some of this. Follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/78413?hl=en

Although it does not solve completely the question, you will be able to define one columns color based on a cell's value.

Hope it helped.

P.s: While I was testing it I have encountered some bugs in this feature so it may very well happen that it won't be really useful. We'll see...